# Using Closure Library on Phonegap(Android) application

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, internationalization, google-closure-library

Hi has any one used google's Closure Library https://developers.google.com/closure/ in building Phonegap applications on Android. I have read that Closure has good support for internationalization of applications. So if anyone could provide material they referred or sample snippets to get an idea of how to implement it.

Comment: Your question is fairly vague. Any more details? On a side note, using  Google's Closure library in a mobile app sounds like a good idea, in fact, a project I am helping with is planning on using the Closure Library and Compiler to develop a mobile app for Android and iOS, though we're planning on just using a web view and not using Phonegap.

Comment: I am planning to use Closure library for internationalization of my phonegap application. Currently im using it in my application but i am getting few errors. So I want to find out if anyone has worked on similar stuff here. Also In your project you will be using Closure for the phone browser, correct me if im wrong.

Comment: Essentially, PhoneGap just displays your code using a WebView, but it adds some extra APIs available through to the JavaScript. I've done things with WebViews where I added functions that JavaScript could call to play audio. PhoneGap essentially does the same thing.

Comment: Ok, So have you started using closure into your application.

Comment: Not yet, we're still in the planning stages, but I have been using Closure not on mobile.

Comment: take a look at this: https://developers.google.com/closure/templates/docs/translation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no difference as to how you use PhoneGap. Framing a web view inside a native app background, doesn't change.

The Closure Library, unlike any other library, will compile your javascript to raw heavily minified code with semantic features.
otherwise yes, use it as you please, PhoneGap included.

When you build something with Closure, you can render the DOM in JavaScript. It is super fast and much much better than the conventional way.

so you create your pages with `goog.dom.createDom`. Below you will find an example.

```
var menuButton = goog.dom.createDom('a', {
    'class': 'menu-button',
    'otherAttributes': 'otherValues etc'
}, myproject.translations.menuButton.currentLanguage);

//Now you have a file like this:
goog.provide('myproject.translations');

// Language variations corresponding to that element.
myproject.translations.menuButton = {
    'EN': 'go',
    'FR': 'aller',
    'DE': 'gehen'//etc...

};
```

Do the above wherever translations are needed. Then simply set the current language on load with something very easy like.

```
myproject.boot = function(parameters) {
    myproject.translations.currentLanguage = parameters['currentLanguage'];
};
goog.exportSymbol('myproject.boot', myproject.boot);
```

and then call the boot method inside the index.php or whatever on window.load and echo a JSON string with the boot parameters from the server. Beware, everything that comes from the server must be encapsulated within quotes when referenced. Otherwise the compiler will flatten the property name in ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS mode.

Comment: Yes i do agree wat you said, but i wanna know how to do localization of strings using closure.js.

Comment: If you want to do localization using the "google" way, you need to compile a seperate js file for every locale - actually, by default the compiler assumes en_US locale for any of its libraries that you may use that has locale support. I do not know if it is possible to select locale at runtime for those libraries (if you use them), but I doubt it.